# Issue for reposition after delete UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am building Application in iOS swift 3.0. I am creating dynamic UIViews. I need to remove custom view randomly, But currently I am unable to relocate the positions as I get the gaps between the two views and I want remove them, as shows in the picture with code below, Kindly help me with this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
var myView: subView! 
var y : CGFloat! 
var tag : Int = 0 
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    y = 1
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func cancelbutton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
            let selectViewTagValue : Int = sender.tag /// save the selected view tag value
            for object in self.view.subviews {

            if ((object is subView) && object.tag == selectViewTagValue)
            {
                object.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
}
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    y = y + 110
    myView = subView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: y, width: 300, height: 100))
    myView.tag = tag 
    myView.actionButton.tag = tag
    tag = tag + 1
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    myView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(cancelbutton(_:))), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myView)

}
```

[image]
[image]

Please Help me this issue... "Thanks in advance"

Comment: Have you tried using Stack View?

Comment: No,  Please send any reference link, Thank you.

Comment: Let of auto-layout form your page and you'll be able to use good old fashioned frame setting. "We never had this conversation".

Comment: You should use UITableView. it 's much more simple - Each view  is a uitableivewcell.  Delete and Insert cell in UItableview is also very simple

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple similar views to be displayed and re-arranged dynamically, `UITableView` is a smart choice. Re-arranging frames would be tedious to maintain and requires lot of code to implement. Why not use tools provided by `UITableView`? Just use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` to delete your view and the rest will be taken care for you.